# Sharepoint date and time column validation

Tags: sharepoint

Google searches are producing complex formulas that I don't understand.

It seems simple enough what I want to accomplish.

I have a calendar date selector that I wish to restrict the selection to within 7 days. I don't want the user to be able to select a date in the past or past 7 days.

My syntax started off as `=[Checkin Date]>=TODAY()`

This works well to restrict a selection in the past. How do I add to this formula so that the user cannot select a date 7 days past the current date?

Can't seem to wrap my head around it need assistance, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try below list validation formula.

```
=IF(INT(OrderDate-NOW())>=-7,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: Have you updated the field OrderDate as your field? I have tested this formula in my local.

Comment: Does it matter if my field is not one word, for instance Checkin Date

Comment: Use [field name] if field contains blank space

Comment: I changed my column name to the same as yours and it does not work, it allows me to select a date past 7 days....nvm dude thanks for trying

Comment: Figured this out myself with the following formula: =AND([Due Date]>=TODAY(),[Due Date]<=(TODAY()+7))

Answer (score 0):

=AND([Due Date]>=TODAY(),[Due Date]<=(TODAY()+7))

This code does exactly what I wanted.
It does not allow the user to select a date in the past, it also will not let the user select a date past 7 days. Perfecto